# Fourier transform and the heat semigroup

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Let $f \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ and $t > 0$. I want to prove that:
$$\mathcal{F}({e^{t\Delta}f})(k) = e^{-t|2\pi k|^{2}}\mathcal{F}(f)(k),$$
where $\Delta$ denotes the Laplacian operator on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform:
$$(\mathcal{F}f)(k) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}e^{-2\pi i \langle k,x\rangle}f(x)dx.$$

I know the following result from functional analysis: let $\mathscr{H}_{1}$ and $\mathscr{H}_{2}$ be Hilbert spaces and $T: \mathscr{H}_{1} \to \mathscr{H}_{1}$ and $S: \mathscr{H}_{2} \to \mathscr{H}_{2}$ be two self-adjoint (possibly unbounded) which are unitarily equivalent, that is, $T = U^{-1}SU$ for some unitary operator $U: \mathscr{H}_{1} \to \mathscr{H}_{2}$. Then, for every continuous and bounded function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$, one has $f(T) = U^{-1}f(S)U$.

Can I use this result to prove the formula above? My idea is: let $f(x) = e^{-x}$ and consider $T = -t\Delta$ and $U = \mathcal{F}$, which is an unitary map. The point that is not clear to me is: $f(x) = e^{-x}$ is not bounded on $\mathbb{R}$, but it is bounded on $[0,\infty)$, which is the spectrum of $-t \Delta$. Can I use the formula in this case? In other words, is it enough that $f$ is bounded and continuous on the spectrum of $T$?

Comment: Are you starting from some other definition of the heat semigroup (like the physical space representation)? I’m not sure how you’d expect to find the heat semigroup without using the heat equation. The standard approach is to take the Fourier transform of the heat equation $\Delta u = \partial_t u$ and solve the resulting ODE with $f$ as your initial data, since $u = e^{t\Delta}f$.

Comment: @Snoop I am actually trying to prove the formula $e^{t\Delta}f(x) = (4\pi t)^{d/2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}f(x)e^{-|x-y|^{2}/4t}dy$. This is why I am using the kernel in Fourier space.

Comment: From functional calculus and the fact that $-t\Delta$ is a positive operator, you can just consider the bounded continuous function $e^{-|x|}$ instead ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be the spectral measure of $- \Delta$.

First of all we do not need a bounded function to use the spectral theorem, it only needs to be measurable.

To answer the question in the last paragraph:
The spectral measure is supported in the spectrum, meaning that $E(\sigma (- \Delta)) = I$ from which it follows that $E(\mathbb{R}\setminus \sigma( - \Delta)) = 0$. Therefore the values outside of the spectrum of the measurable function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for which we want to define $f(-\Delta)$ do not influence $f(-\Delta)$. Meaning that we can redefine $f$ outside the spectrum as we please (for example set it to $0$). Therefore $f(-\Delta)$ will be continuous if $f$ is bounded on the spectrum.

In this case we have that $- \Delta$ is unitarily equivalent via the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F}$ to the operator $M_g$ that is given by the multiplication with the function $g$ defined by $g(k)= |2\pi k|^2 $.
Let $F$ be the spectral measure of $M$.
Per [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4788403/equality-ft-ufsu-for-continuous-functions-on-operators) post we know that $E = \mathcal{F}^* F \mathcal{F}$. It can be shown that for a multiplication operator $f(M_g)= M_{f \circ g}$ and therefore
$$f(- \Delta ) =\mathcal{F}^* f(M_g)\mathcal{F} =  \mathcal{F}^* M_{f \circ g} \mathcal{F}.$$
The desired formula is obtained by setting (for a fixed $t>0$) $f (x)= \exp (-t x)$ for $ x\in \mathbb{R}$. The formula also holds for all $L^2$ functions, since $\exp (t \Delta)$ is bounded (and not just on $H^1$).

Most of this post works generally and not just for the specific operator under consideration here.